# Problem with printing - Inheritance, Polymorphism and toString

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, tostring

I am practicing how to use toString(), polymorphism and inheritance. Right now I have the code below and it has all the information that I want to print and it does print but I have some unwanted lines.

[image]

I just need the 1st and 3rd line but I'm not so sure why it's printing out the other 3 lines.

```
public class Test_toString{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Car c = new Car();
        System.out.println(c.toString());

        NamedCar c2 = new NamedCar(160, 8, "green", "Pony");
        System.out.println(c2.toString());
    }
}

class Car{
    int speed;
    int gear;
    public String color;

    public Car(){
        speed = 100;
        gear = 5;
        color = "silver";
    }

    public Car(int speed, int gear, String color){
        this.speed = speed;
        this.gear = gear;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "Car: " + speed + "km/h " + gear + " gears " +
        color + "\n" + super.toString();
    }
}

class NamedCar extends Car{
    public String name;

    public NamedCar(String name){
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }

    public NamedCar(int speed, int gear, String color, String name){
        this.speed = speed;
        this.gear = gear;
        this.color = color;
        this.name = name;
    }


    public String toString(){
        return "Car: " + speed + "km/h " + gear + " gears " +
        color + " " +  name + "\n" + super.toString(); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove method call super.toString() from toString() method in both classes.
When you make that call you are calling toString() method from parent class. So when it is called from NamedCar class, it calls toString() method from Car class and when it is called from Car class it calls toString() from object class.

Answer (score 1):

when you call `super.toString()` you are calling `toString()` method of `parent` class in your `child` class.

All the classes you define as a user are a `child` of `Object` class. so your calling `Object.toString()` method in this part of your code:

```
public String toString(){
    return "Car: " + speed + "km/h " + gear + " gears " +
    color + "\n" + super.toString();
}
```

which is a part of `toString()` method of your `Car` class.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, all classes by default extend Object, thus they can use the methods defined there, such as hashCode() or toString(), where toString() by default returns a hash representation of the object.

Now to get back to your example.
You have an inheritance setup such as this

-- Object 
-- Car extends Object
-- NamedCar extends Car

when you create a Car and print it, it will call the toString() method defined in Object and it returns you the hashCode of this particular object (the instance of Car in this case). When you write your own public String toString() method (as you have done) and you try to print the Car again, it will call the toString() of the Car Class and therefore print you your

```
"Car: " + speed + "km/h " + gear + " gears " + color + "\n"
```

however you are also calling super.toString();  which will go to the parent class and get the value of its toString(), thus the hashCode representation of the object.

Now - fast-forward to the NamedCar. As you may have guessed it follows the same principle.

when calling the toString() method here, it prints your correct details

```
"Car: " + speed + "km/h " + gear + " gears " + color + " " +  name
```

but then you include the toString() of the parent class by super.toString()
therefore it will then call the respective method of the Class Car.

However, since NamedCar is also a Car, it also uses the fields defined in Car,
namely:

```
int speed;
int gear;
public String color;
```

so when the super.toString() is called and it uses them, you get them in your 4th line.